# Equivalent of xen capping in kvm

Tags: xen, kvm-virtualization

I have been using xen hypervisor. I use the credit scheduler and make use of capping in credit scheduler. Now I am migrating to KVM . Is there any good equivalent of that VM capping in kvm ? Any help or pointers will be great. Thank you.

-Sethu

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at cgroups.  They can be used to limit resources to VMs.

This Red Hat [document](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Resource_Management_Guide/index.html) on resource management is a pretty good introduction to cgroups.

Comment: It provides weight and not cap right ?

Comment: I believe it can also provide a hard limit to the amount of resources a cgroup can use.  But it can also be used to give priorities to the VMs.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups

Comment: This blog post goes more into how to use Cgroups with KVM.  http://berrange.com/posts/2009/12/03/using-cgroups-with-libvirt-and-lxckvm-guests-in-fedora-12/

Comment: Yeah it provides cpu shares. The shares dont provide a hard limit such that It cannot cross that limit, if there is only 1 vm and if i set the shares to be 50% or 512, i want the usage to be restricted to 50% max but it will let the vm let it use more unless there is another VM using the rest 50% of the share and fighting with the vm we set a limit on.

Comment: Yeah looking into this more looks like the only hard limit cgroups allows currently is memory use.  But I did run across this.  lkml.org/lkml/2009/6/4/24 and http://lwn.net/Articles/428175/ which seems to indicate that it's coming in a future kernel release.  Googling for cpu.cfs_quota_us provides a bunch of additional information.

Comment: Can you take a look at cpulimit and let me know whether it will work? http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/ ..... I am a little bit skeptic about it.

Comment: That may be a decent option until cpu.cfs_quota_us for cgroups is in place.  The way it works sounds reasonable to me and with KVM each VM is just a process.  I'd do some testing before rolling it out into production though.

Comment: Yeah sounds like a good option. I want to know is it available in centos 6? I am using centos 6 and i can see only shares.

Comment: It looks like cpu.cfs_quota_us has an upper limit of 1 second, so it can't be used for building credit over a day (like AWS t2 instances) https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu.html Would love to find out I'm wrong.